# Trusted timestamping log files in Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ubuntu, timestamp, ubuntu-9.10, trusted-timestamp

We have an ubuntu 9.10 server. There are some log files need to be archived and they must be timestamped to guarantee no change in time. I've found [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_timestamping) but couldn't found a proper solution for my current needs.

Is there any command to sign log files with a trusted timestamp in Ubuntu?

Regards,
Burak

Answer (score 1):

First you need to have a TSA or a timestamping authority in your network to call to timestamp do you have one? try http://www.opentsa.org/

Comment: Thanks but it seems a bit old. 9.10 has ubuntu 0.9.8g.